# Find the probability - group of 3 people know each other

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

There are 300 peoples in a room. The probability that each pair know each other, independently, is **p**.

Estimate the probability that there is at least one group of 3 people in which all 3 know each other.

I'm pretty sure that the answer should use the Inclusion–exclusion principle, but I'm not sure how should I find an estimation.

Comment: Well, a crude first step might be to assume that every triple is independent.    That assumption is false, of course as, say, the triples $(A,B,C), (A,B, D)$ both depend on whether $A$ knows $B$ or not.  But as an approximation, it might not be bad.

Comment: This question is a variant of the Birthday Problem--  On a planet where the length of a year is $1/p$ days, what is the probability that in a group of $300$ people, at least $3$ have the same birthday?